# Filtering SharePoint List by Another SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part, filter, web

I've been searching the forums and doing research online with no luck- apologies if this has been answered before.

I have a list with several thousand items in it. I often receive bulk update requests where I need to update several hundred of these items at a time (let's say for this example that we're using a field called "Case ID").

Here's what I've tried:

- Searching cases individually, or up to three at a time in datasheet view; this is not time effective
- Exporting the list and manually manipulating the data in Excel, then pasting in (and writing over) the data in the column that needs to be updated; this approach is not user friendly, is not necessarily time effective, and has potential side effects (causing errors for users currently modifying items that I am changing in bulk)
- Lastly- I know I can create custom views that isolate this data; the problem is that the lists of cases I need to modify generally do not have enough commonalities to isolate them using the view filter logic

So- my guess is that I need two lists, likely connected with a web part. The first list would exist solely for the purpose of querying the second list. I would enter the Case IDs I wanted to filter by in the first list, and the second list would filter to show only the Case IDs in the first list. All items would be deleted from the first list between queries.

I'm not married to this approach- it's just my best guess. I'm open to creative and alternative approached, but the final process needs to be user friendly (business partners will be using it).

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I've tried to get something implemented several times over the past few years and have never been successful; posting here is my last resort before I throw in the towel.

I have SP 2013, and have SharePoint Designer; please let me know if I need to add any other information.

Thanks in advance for the support,

Chad

UPDATE: After posting this I realized it really belonged on Stack Overflow instead. I re-posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451017/filtering-sharepoint-list-by-another-sharepoint-list

I hope it's not bad form to cross post like this.

Comment: If it were me, i'd probably opt to do this in an Access database. Link the SharePoint table in the database, create a local table in the database to put the Case ID's in, then create a join query so that you're only returning records you need.  You can then update the records directly in the select query and since it's a linked table it'll update the SharePoint record.

Comment: Nate- I agree that this is a great approach, and this is what I would do I I were the only one using this tool. The issue is that I need this to be usable by less tech-savvy users, and I don’t think they’ll be comfortable doing anything in Access. Thanks for your the suggestion though!